# Gravitational field strength

Tags: particle-physics, newtonian-gravity, estimation, subatomic

Can I use $g=GM/r^2$ to calculate the gravitational field strength proton or electron or any other particles? If not then why? If yes then what would be that really mean?

Answer (score 1):

You could use Newton's classic equation, but, as illustrated in an answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/382637/gravitational-binding-energy-for-atoms), its effects would be almost negligible.

Aside from that, we don't know if Newtonian gravity even applies to particles on that scale. To answer that question would require a theory of quantum gravity which, to date, has not yet been developed.

Answer (score 0):

Usually (that I know of) the noticeable differences between General Relativity and Newtonian gravity only become apparent on a macroscopic, $>=$ planetary scale. 
 For example the [precession of Mercurcy](http://physics.ucr.edu/~wudka/Physics7/Notes_www/node98.html), [light bending](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_lens), black holes etc...

So for atomic scales, you can use the Newtonian formula, yes.

It tells you the strength of the gravitational field generated by, say, a proton of mass *m*. So if you place a test mass of mass $m_1$, it will experience a force towards the proton $F = m_1g$. 
 Due to the low masses and the small value of $G$, gravitational effects on atoms are almost always superseded by the electromagnetic interaction - i.e. a proton and an electron will form an EM-bound state before they would form a gravitational bound state (an orbit), or simply scatter from one another.

Comment: With position, etc. not being well defined, I doubt that  Newtonian laws are good at small scales.