# Gravitational binding energy for atoms?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, experimental-physics, atomic-physics, estimation

Atoms are a bound state of electrons and protons held together by the EM force, in the same way a quarks are bound by the strong force etc.

All these particles being massive though, gravitational attraction should make a (albeit small) contribution to the binding energy.

Has any experiment every measured this discrepancy? What precision would be necessary to test this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mass of the electron is roughly $10^{-30}$ kg. The mass of the proton iis roughly $10^{-27}$ kg. The distance between them is roughly $10^{-10}$ m. Inserting these into the formula for gravitational binding energy:

$$U=\frac{Gm_pm_e}{r}=\frac{10^{-11}\times 10^{-27}\times 10^{-30}}{10^{-10}}=10^{-58}\textrm{ J}=10^{-40}\textrm{ eV}$$

The most sensitive energy measurement we have ever made (i.e. the Harvard Tower version of the Pound-Rebka experiment) measured an energy difference of $10^{-11}$ eV.

Comment: I should probably add that we don't even know if Newtonian gravity even applies at quantum scales.

Comment: Even though this shows that this measurement is not feasible, one might want to mention that it is not even possible in principle since we cannot make the proton heavier, nor switch off gravity. To make this measurement feasible in principle, one may have to do something crazy like trapping a particle that interacts only gravitational (clearly, the neutron does not qualify) at the position of the proton.

Comment: @marmot Why do we need to make the proton heavier or switch off gravity to measure this? There are definitely possible experiments that involve neither of those things. For example, gravitational attraction perturbs the energy levels of hydrogen very slightly; just look for tiny, tiny offsets to the wavelengths of the hydrogen emission spectrum that match what theory would predict for the action of gravity.

Comment: I thought you want to measure the effect of gravity on the binding energies in atoms. This requires a comparison between the binding energies with and without gravity.

Comment: @marmot By measuring how much the hydrogen spectrum deviates from what you would predict using QM without gravity, we are measuring the effect of gravity on the binding energy of hydrogen.

Comment: Er... you are aware of the fact that there all sorts of corrections which are much larger than this effect? That is, once you show me computation that calculates the levels to the precision $10^{-4o}$ eV, we can continue this discussion. BTW, I also do not agree with your statement on the maximal precision in experiments, see e.g. the Pound–Rebka experiment. This is my final comment here.

Comment: @marmot I am aware. I was including any and all non-gravitational corrections in "what you would predict using QM without gravity." Apply whatever corrections are necessary, then compare prediction to experiment. And I don't have to show you that we can currently get this precision in our prediction, because that wasn't what you objected about. You said that it was impossible _in principle_, not just impossible _today_. (You also, by the way, changed the principle upon which you were objecting; you're no longer mentioning turning off gravity, objecting on purely technical grounds now.)

Comment: @marmot And I had forgotten about the Pound-Rebka experiment, thank you. The answer is edited to reflect this. Though I'm a little puzzled why you didn't bring that up in the first place.

Comment: ... because there are also atomic clock transitions and so on, but really because your answer is conceptually misleading, at best. I tried to politely tell you that but all you are doing is to place an update in which you do not even mention the source ....  (did it occur to you that also the Higgs mediates an attractive force much stronger than gravity at these distances?)

Comment: @marmot I'm not sure what atomic clock transitions have to do with anything. The effect from the Higgs field can also be included in the corrections I alluded to in my last comment, once theory and computational physics progresses to the point where we can predict their effects with enough precision. Let me ask you again: why is it impossible _in principle_ to do this experiment? All of your objections are things that would make it merely _impractical_.

Comment: I've explained it over and over. In order to measure the effect of gravity, you need to he able to compare the situations with and without gravity.

Comment: @marmot "In order to measure the effect of the Higgs field, you need to be able to compare the situations with and without the Higgs field." So we shouldn't be able to say the Higgs field exists, either, since we can't turn it off. See how that argument doesn't make sense?

Comment: Let's just agree to disagree. (The Higgs has different Yukawa couplings to different fermions, which enables a comparison.)

Comment: @marmot Just as gravity has different couplings to particles of different masses.

Comment: We just agree to disagree. (If you were right, in atoms in which one replaces an electron my a muon, the only difference would be the gravitational energy. A very nice proof that muon induced fusion is wrong.) This is my final comment. Everyone can read through these comments and build her or his own opinion on how convincing your arguments are. Please stop at this point.

Comment: @marmot I never said that gravitational energy would be the only difference. All I said is that it would be different, and all I'm trying to show you is that turning off gravity is not necessary to measure its effect. Also, muon-catalyzed fusion has been observed since 1954: https://escholarship.org/uc/item/5pp2h0qp. Not sure what you think is "wrong" about it, nor am I quite certain what it has to do with what we're talking about.